# Constant for initial value problem equals 0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving the IVP

$$\frac{dh}{dt}(a+be^{(-ct)} )+fh = 0 $$
with initial condition $h(0)=0$.

Wolfram gives the answer general solution as $h =k(ae^{ct}+b)^{\frac{f}{ac}}$

If I pair this with the i.c. it seems I would have to use $k=0$ to satisfy the constraint.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Why do you not like the solution $h(t)=0$ for all $t$?

Comment: Because I'm wanting the equation to describe hydraulic head change in an aquifer due to. The system has h(0)=0 but at t>0  h should not be zero.

Comment: The solution to your ODE is $h(t)\equiv 0$ for $h(0)=0$. If you want a non-zero solution you need a different initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $b=-a$, then:

$$h(0)=k(ae^{c\cdot0}+b)^{f/ac}=k(a-a)^{f/ac}=0\\h(t\neq0)=k(ae^{ct}-a)^{f/ac}\neq0\iff k\neq0$$

This was because $e^0=1$, so $ae^{c\cdot0}=a\cdot1=a$.